# Non-romantic variant of "to cuddle"

Tags: single-word-requests

I have an interesting problem; for a story, I'd need a word that is almost equivalent to "cuddle" (as an emotionally intensive touching) but without implied erotic context that someone may feel in it (or not?).

I considered "snuggle", "embrace", "hug", but these are passive; they imply embracing the object and doing nothing more.

In the story, it is an activity of a protagonist who finds herself fascinated by the look and shape of a friendly, blob-like alien creature:

> She sat close, and it smiled peacefully; she extended her hand, and it put its head on it, and then she snuggled to it, embraced it, ______, stroked it, gently tickled and squeezed and profoundly enjoyed the tactile experience, while the creature purred silently and rubbed its head and ears against her.

The closest example of such activity in real life might be what does a pet owner to her beloved cat. Maybe also a mother to her little baby.

Any ideas, please? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I'd say that *cuddle* **is** the right word. When used with babies or animals, there's no "erotic context". In fact, my dictionary has the example: "he cuddles the baby close".

Comment: a bear hug perhaps!

Comment: Laurel: thank you! :-) It's good to know that my intuitive choice of word was not completely off... I might leave "cuddling" there but I'll wait a bit to see if someone does not bring a counterexample. (I'm a bit afraid as the story is very emotional at that point - the protagonist starts to develop motherly feelings toward the creature - and an unwanted hint of erotica would break the atmosphere to pieces).

Comment: Jonathan: thank you! Another nice word for the story :-)
Mahmud: bear hug contains a bit too much squeezing for this specific use :-) but thanks, it will be useful in another context :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that any implication of your eventual choice is mostly derived from the context. You also happen to have chosen alternatives such as **embrace**, which might fit your description. Whilst it's not your question, perhaps reconsidering the number of verbs might help.

Or why not swap it out for something more physical than implied? How about **cradle** for example?

For reference, here in Wales we have a specific verb/noun for almost what you need - a non-erotic, usually longer-duration, affectionate hug or embrace - **cwtch**. Forgive me for quoting Urban Dictionary, but it's defined there as:

> Welsh word for an affectionate hug. There's no literal English
>   translation, but its nearest equivlent is "safe place". So if you give
>   someone a cwtch, you're giving them a "safe place".

Comment: cwtch - that's a beautiful word (and the idea behind it), nice to know :-)

Comment: "cradle" is a nice alternative to "embrace", with the added hint of safety - thank you :-)

I will definitely use it elsewhere, but for this specific case, it is still a bit passive - the protagonist is, like with a cat, stroking and touching the other's body in changing patterns (it might also be exploratory as she never touched, and barely seen, anything like that).

Ah, yes, I tend to clump synonymic verbs together; I have to limit it a bit. Thanks for noticing. :-)

Comment: +1 for the first para, and tip. the Welsh verb is not English, please find a reference that supports its usage. UD in this case might be acceptable if you include a link, and we can see how many readers have give it the thumbs up.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The Welsh word (verb and noun, spelt identically) is in frequent use in English here as a loanword. With respect, a quick Google for the word will allay usage concerns.

Comment: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cwtch But good answers are supposedly self contained on SE, are they not?

Comment: With respect, never heard or seen *cwtch* before in my life.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Indeed, which is why I defined it in two forms.

Comment: @Clare Have you spent much time in Wales or with Welsh people? I'd be surprised if so.

Comment: My bad, Dan. I failed to see the "here *in Wales"* qualification.